# Pasting Clipboard to new Workbook VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy, paste

I'm trying to loop through files in a folder, copy data of unknown size from each file, and paste them all below each other in a new workbook. I can't seem to be able to get the clipboard to paste properly as it always gives me a runtime error 9, Subscript out of range.

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    Dim StrFile As String
    StrFile = Dir("filepath")

    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim itemized As Excel.Workbook
    Dim dump As Excel.Workbook

    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        MsgBox StrFile
        Set dump = Workbooks.Open("dump.xlsx")
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open("StrFile")
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

        Worksheets("DATA2").Visible = True
        Worksheets("DATA2").Activate
        Application.Goto Reference:="R1C1:R98C1"
        Selection.EntireRow.Delete
        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Select
        Selection.Copy

        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now())

        Set dump = ActiveWorkbook
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Activate
        ActiveCell.SendKeys ("^v")
        StrFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few things that are potentially issues.

1) when you open the workbook for "StrFile" you have it in quotes:

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("StrFile")
```

This means you're literally looking for a workbook named "StrFile."  If you remove the quotes, it will instead interpolate the contents of the variable, which, I believe is what you want

2) It is unclear to me which document you want to copy and paste from and to.  Your description seems clear enough, but there is confusion within your code.  You refer to "active" objects -- better, I think, to explicitly call out which object you want to copy and paste from and to.

In other words, replace calls where you assign the Activeworkbook, and just use the workbook instead

3) Strictly speaking, it isn't *wrong* to do select/copy/paste, but you can skip a step by doing the copy/paste directly.  Better yet, you can avoid the use of the clipboard by copying one range to another

4) You didn't ask, but maybe close the workbook when you're done with it

Without suggestion #3, this is how it might look:

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    Dim StrFile As String
    StrFile = Dir("filepath")

    Dim wb, itemized, dump As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        'MsgBox StrFile
        Set dump = Workbooks.Open("dump.xlsx")
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(StrFile)

        wb.Worksheets("DATA2").Activate  ' specify which workbook directly
        Application.Goto Reference:="R1C1:R98C1"

        Selection.EntireRow.Delete

        wb.Range("A1").Copy   ' specify which wb to copy FROM

        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now())

        ' specify which workbook to copy TO
        dump.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

        wb.Close

        StrFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

With suggestion #3 you can eliminate the copy/paste with something like this:

```
dump.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value2 = wb.Range("A1").Value2
```

This can be a big help if other applications are trying to use the clipboard.